# Extracting dates that exist in another dataframe within each subject (R)

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, both with different dates:

Dataframe 1

```
ID    Date
A    21/1/2018
A    22/1/2018
B    21/1/2018
B    26/2/2018
C    19/9/2019
```

Dataframe 2

```
ID    Date
A    21/1/2018
A    22/1/2018
A    23/1/2018
B    21/1/2018
B    22/1/2018
B    23/1/2018
C    20/1/2018
C    04/5/2018
```

I want to extract only the dates from Dataframe 2 that are present in each participant in Dataframe 1:

```
 ID    Date
A    21/1/2018
A    22/1/2018
B    21/1/2018
```

or some kind of row index:

```
[1 2 4]
```

I can probably do it with nested loops, but my data contains tens of thousands of  cases, so am wondering if there is any more computationally efficient method in R for doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, it seems like `merge(df2, df1)` should just work.

```
merge(df2, df1)
  ID      Date
1  A 21/1/2018
2  A 22/1/2018
3  B 21/1/2018
```

Comment: merge works perfectly with a few additional options:


merge(df2, df1, by=c('ID', 'Date'))

Answer (score 2):

If you have two date vectors:

```
 dates1 <- seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/01/10'), by="day")

 dates2 <- seq(as.Date('1999/01/08'), as.Date('1999/01/15'), by="day")
```

you can then find the indices of the dates you want with

```
which(dates2 %in% dates1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter as below:

```
df2[df2$Date %in% df1$Date, ]
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to find out `dates` which are present in same `ID` from both the dataframes. We can `split` both the dataframes based on `ID` and find out `Date` in `df2` which are present in `df1` and extract those rows.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) x[x$Date %in% y$Date, ], 
              split(df2, df2$ID), split(df1, df1$ID)))

#  ID      Date
#A.1  A 21/1/2018
#A.2  A 22/1/2018
#B    B 21/1/2018
```

---

You can also get the row index by doing

```
df2$row <- 1:nrow(df2)
unname(unlist(Map(function(x, y) x$row[x$Date %in% y$Date], 
              split(df2, df2$ID), split(df1, df1$ID))))
#[1] 1 2 4
```